# Question about Unity Code (Can build for PC but not Mobile)

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile

[image: platformer]

I am designing a 2D platformer on Unity that I want to deploy to my mobile phone.

However, when I try to Build and Run to my Android device, I keep getting error.

This is my code:

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(5, rb.velocity.y);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(5, 8);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Win")
        {
            UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
            Application.Quit();
        }
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Lose")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Before I added my OnTriggerEnter2D(), the game could build and run on my Android fine. After adding it in, there were errors.

I suspect that it has got to do with maybe the EditorApplication.isPlaying = false? And maybe also the SceneManager.LoadScene()?

Are there alternative codes that I can use?

I want the game to close when I win, and "restart" when I lose.

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue comes with this line:

```
    UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
```

You cannot include the UnityEditor.dll in the builds. you should also ensure you are not using it in your namespaces.

Or, you can encapsulate it with a preprocessor

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
#endif
```